# Get month from data stored as string in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I'm getting  the date from user and storing it as sting in database. For example my date in database looks "22/09/2014". Now I want to get only month(September) from that date. How can I get that?

My Code is

```
public ArrayList<String> getMonths(){
    String SELECT_MON = "select strftime('%m',"
            + Diary_DBHandler.PERSONAL_DATE + ") from " + Diary_DBHandler.TABLE_PERSONAL + ";";
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(SELECT_MON, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    ArrayList<String> mon=new ArrayList<String>();
    if (c != null)
    {
         while(!c.isAfterLast()) {
             System.out.println(mon);
            mon.add(c.getString(0));
            c.moveToNext(); 
         }
   c.close();
 }
return mon;
}
```

Comment: [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is your friend. Use it to parse the db string, get its `Calendar`, and then the month from that.

Comment: `strftime()` only works on **well formed** dates (`2014-09-22`), not the `22/09/2014` format

Comment: But how can use the data from database in SimpleDateFormat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get a [Date](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) object with a `SimpleDateFormat`. The pattern for your String ("22/09/2014") is `dd/MM/yyyy`

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
```

From the date you can build a [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) object

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.setTime(date);
```

and from the [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) you can extract easily the month, with

```
 cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to convert a string date to Date format

```
String dateString = "03/26/2012 11:49:00 AM";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
    Date convertedDate = new Date(); 
    try { 
        convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    System.out.println(convertedDate);
```

And if you only want the month, take a look at the method `getMonth();` [Date Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html)

Notice that it's a better way to store the **timestamp** (long) on DB than a string date.